# Rails: Active Record Timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tiny-tds

This is a piece of code in place. When I add this to the cron with `timeout` the  entire array gets saved twice. When I remove timeout nothing gets saved

In this scenario we would want to save the array results (coming in from an api) with over 100k records to be saved to the db. I have used bulk insert and TinyTds gems here

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(adapter: 'sqlserver', host: "xxx", username: "xxx", password: "xxx", database: "xxx", azure: true, port: 1433, timeout: 5000)

class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = 'id'
end

my_array = [] #count of 100000 records
Report.bulk_insert(:account_owner_id) do |worker|
  my_array.drop(2).each do |arr|
    worker.add account_owner_id: arr[0]
  end
end
```

Comment: Can I ask how you are triggering this code? Is it from a controller? Does the same happen is you run it from a script? Is there any chance you can post the schema and the datafile somewhere - or part of the datafile at least.

Comment: I'm running it from a script . This is the code I run . In addition to which I have an api which populates data to my_array . Is there an issue with adding timeout to active record connection. This issue happens when I run the code using cron . There are two scripts which access the database and they both have the same code

Answer (score -1):

You can try removing `timeout` and adding `ignore: true` to your bulk insert as shown [here](https://github.com/jamis/bulk_insert). There may be an insert that is failing.

```
Report.bulk_insert(:account_owner_id, ignore: true) do |worker|
```

Comment: Ignore stops the batch to be inserted - but in my cases it is saving the batch x times.

Comment: It continues if one record fails. From docs: `The ignore option ignores the inserts that would have failed (because of duplicate keys or a null in column with a not null constraint) and inserts the rest of the batch.`